# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getForm' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms, extjs3

I am developing a WebGIS web application, written in java script, to which I am relatively new. The code has to load table data from a postgres database into an EditorGridPanel using AJAX. I am using js ext-3.4.1.

This is my function to load the table data table name: "general_data"

```
function loadTableData(itemId) {

    var jsonStore;          
    //load from DB                  
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        method:'GET',
        url : config.configURL,
        params : {
            type: 'select', 
            code: '008.009',
            table: itemId

        },
        success : function(response){

            if (response.responseText != "[{}]") {

                console.log("jsonStore created from database!")

                var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                jsonStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                    autoLoad: false,
                    fields: Object.keys(data[0]),
                    listeners: {
                         'load': function (store, records, options ) {
                           if(records[0]){
                               Ext.getCmp(itemId).getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
                           } else{
                               console.log("no data!");
                           }
                       }
                    }
                });

                jsonStore.loadData(data);


            }else{

                console.log("Request success, but failed to create jsonStore object!")

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Code:'008.009' is a row ID value in the db (one of multiple) I am using for testing. The error referred to later in this thread oaccurs in the piece of code: Ext.getCmp(itemId).getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);

The grid panel calling the function is:

```
var generaldataGrid2 = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    title:"Accessibility",
    height:'200',
    split : true,
    trackMouseOver : true,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    enableDragDrop: false,
    enableColumnHide:false,
    enableHdMenu: false,
    listeners: {
        "beforeedit": function(e) {
            if (e.record.get("group_user") == "9999") {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    store: loadTableData("general_data"),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    columns: [
        {id: "code", header: 'Code', width: 70, dataIndex: "building_code"},
        {header: 'Building Name', width: 160, dataIndex: "building_name",
            editor:{
                xtype:'textfield',
                allowBlank : false,
                minLength : 1
            },
            renderer: function(val, metadata) {
                metadata.attr = String.format('{0}title="{1}"', metadata.attr, val);
                return val;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

and the grid panel is embedded in a tab panel with the following code:

```
tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    //var tabs = config.tabItems,
    deferredRender:true,
    activeTab: 0,
    region:"south",
    height:'200',
    items: [
        generaldataGrid2
        ]
});
```

When loading the page, a json object is created from the row and columns: 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aHWt.png)

But the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getForm' of undefined
    at constructor.load (custom.js:172)
    at EXTUTIL.Event.fire (ext-all-debug.js:329)
    at constructor.fireEvent (ext-all-debug.js:73)
    at constructor.loadRecords (ext-all-debug.js:24681)
    at constructor.loadData (ext-all-debug.js:24690)
    at success (custom.js:180)
    at Ext.data.Connection.handleResponse (ext-all-debug.js:4661)
    at handleTransactionResponse (ext-base-debug.js:2330)
    at checkResponse (ext-base-debug.js:2378)
    at ext-base-debug.js:1366
```

I am not familiar with forms and only found very little material to work with in the the web up to now. Does anyone have any clues?

Thanks for any type of advice

Comment: `Ext.getCmp(itemId)` is returning `undefined`, you might want to check that out

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have now tried countless times to modify the code for it to load jsonStore with Ext.Cmp properly, yet it is still not working. The json object is created successfully, but Ext.Cmp(itemId).getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);  will still return Ext.Cmp as undefined. Any more tips from anyone?